# ng-click function parameters as $scope variable with angular 1.x

Tags: angularjs, ng-controller

I would like to use the parameters that I get with my ng-click as $scope variable to use it everywhere on my site.

My Controller:

```
music.controller('musicController', function($scope, $rootScope, $location, musicControl) {
  $scope.titles = [
  {
    title: 'New Divide',
    artist: 'Linkin Park',
    album: 'New Divide',
    genre: 'Rock',
    cover: 'new-divide.jpg',
    titleLength: '4:28',
    file: 'test'
  }
  ];
  $scope.playListMusic = function(titleName) {
    $rootScope.titleName = titleName;
    musicControl.playListMusic();
  }
//...
});
```

My ng-click link:

```
<div ng-repeat="title in titles | unique:'album' | filter:search" class="row content">
/...
<span ng-click='playListMusic(title.title)' class="badge music-control">
```

Comment: I suppose that "titleName" being in quotes is accidental, but if so, the passed value is in the variable $scope.titleName.

Comment: You could attach `titleName` to `$rootScope` or define a `service` and store it there.  Also, I think you mean `$scope.titleName = titleName` - without double quotes.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Yes, the double quotes where just a test. I forgot to delete them for Stack Overflow.

Comment: the comment of @JarekKulikowski should be the accepted answer

Comment: How can I attach it to $rootScope. I changes the $scope from the function in a $rootScope and/or the $scope from titleName. But notthing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$rootScope` is an object so

```
$rootScope.titleName = titleName;
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It still not work. The titleName comes from an ng-repeat. Could that be the Problem? I'm adding more information in my first post...

Comment: I don't see how `title` is passed to `html`. Perhaps  you could show the whole `ng-repeat` in `html` and how `$scope.title` is being set.

Comment: I wonder if your `filter` returns what you are expecting.  Otherwise, everything seems fine.

Comment: The filter is for a search field. The array is a list with songs. When I click on one, I will play the exect song I have clicked.

Comment: Ah, I think I see you problem.  You've replaced `$scope.titleName` with `$rootScope.titleName`.  You need both, the first to be used in html `{{...}}` the second to globally store the value of `titleName` in `$rootScope`

Comment: Yep, that was the mistake. Thank you very much. :)